# Designing issues with edited user at programmers

Tags: bug, design, software-engineering-se

[image]

I recently go through this website and i found designing issue with edited user check 178 of yannis its collision with pankaj

[Check here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/121801/understanding-and-developing-web-services)

---

Is this a issue i have **1024 resolution**